# Sorting students based on grade using dictionary

Tags: python

I have come across a practice question which asks the following:

> The function should be called select_student and takes as arguments:
>
> - A list where each element is a list of a student name, and their grade.
> - A grade. The student grade must be superior or equal to the given grade to be accepted.
>
> Your function must return a dictionnary with two entries:
>
> - Accepted which list the accepted students sorted by grades in the descending order.
> - Refused which list the refused students sorted by grades in ascending order.

So far I have:

```
def select_students(student, threshold):
  
   entries = {"Accepted" : "", "Refused" : ""}

   for x in student:
 
       if x[1] <= threshold:    
           entries["Refused"] = "x"
    
       else:
           entries["Accepted"] = "x"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
     a = [['Kermit Wade', 27], ['Hattie Schleusner', 67], ['Ben Ball', 5], ['William Lee', 2]]
     print(select_students(a, 20))
```

This code does not work and I'm not sure how to make it all work, converting the list into a dictionary and then having keys with no values where you can conditionally append the values. The result is supposed to look like this:

```
{'Accepted': [['Hattie Schleusner', 67], ['Kermit Wade', 27]],
 'Refused': [['William Lee', 2], ['Ben Ball', 5]]}
```

Comment: Why is Kermit Wade accepted when her grade is 27 and the threshold is 50?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to build the dictionary response as you iterate over the input data it will be easier to build two lists.

Then, you can more easily sort the lists as you construct the response dictionary.

Something like this:

```
def select_students(students, threshold):
    accepted, refused = [], []
    for entry in students:
        (accepted if entry[1] >= threshold else refused).append(entry)
    return {
        'Accepted': sorted(accepted, key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True),
        'Refused': sorted(refused, key=lambda e: e[1])
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = [['Kermit Wade', 27], ['Hattie Schleusner', 67], ['Ben Ball', 5], ['William Lee', 2]]
    print(select_students(students, 50))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Accepted': [['Hattie Schleusner', 67]], 'Refused': [['William Lee', 2], ['Ben Ball', 5], ['Kermit Wade', 27]]}
```

Comment: I didn't think to do that, thank you so much!